# my database loads all of my data in listview every time database called

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am pretty sure my `sqlite` syntax is right but I don't know why when database result is loaded in my `listview` it show all of my data. I think the problem is about my cursor snippet.

How can I fix this problem that load only rows where `table_one.id = table_two.day_id`

```
 @Override
    public List<Model> getAllEx() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_ONE + " INNER JOIN " + Constants.TABLE_TWO +" ON "+
                Constants.ID_ONE + " = " + Constants.ID_DAY;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            Model model = new Model();
            model.setSecond_id(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.ID_TWO)));
            model.setExercise(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.EXERSICE)));
            model.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.NUMBER)));
            model.setReps(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.REPS)));
            model.setId_day(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.ID_DAY)));

            list.add(model);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what values you have in your constants but is your query like this `select * from table_one as one inner join table_two as two on one.id = two.day_id`

Comment: @Rohit5k2  it doesnt work for me. again loading list in every category the same.

Comment: Shouldn't you use a where clause where you check for category while fetching data from DB?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 you'r right , but shouldn't i join tables first?  i dont know the syntax of joining tables and using WHERE in my code

Comment: Yes you should join it first. Adding it in my answer.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: @Rohit5k2  tnx now im gonna check it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what values you have in your constants but is your query like this

```
select * from table_one as one inner join table_two as two 
    on one.id = two.day_id 
    where one.category="cat_one" 
       and two.category="cat_two"
```

You can remove the category of second/first table if not required.

Comment: what should i use instead of my category?

Comment: @Maggot: That depends how you want to filter the data.